# Using Java to gather specific system information: monitor (screen) details

Tags: java

I know it is possible to get system information in Java and have searched SO for this particular question but have come up empty.

**Question:**
Can I gather complete system information about all attached monitors? Particularly I am hoping to get a unique ID, model number, or manufacturer of each monitor.

Wayan Saryada for example demonstrated a simple example here that gets basic information about all connected monitors. Code follows to protect from link rot:

```
    //
    // Get local graphics environment
    //
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

    GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();

    int sequence = 1;
    for (GraphicsDevice device : devices) {
        System.out.println("Screen Number [" + (sequence++) + "]");
        System.out.println("Width       : " + device.getDisplayMode().getWidth());
        System.out.println("Height      : " + device.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
        System.out.println("Refresh Rate: " + device.getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate());
        System.out.println("Bit Depth   : " + device.getDisplayMode().getBitDepth());
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

This code however produces nothing unique. Its just generic information that is helpful but does not meet my end goal.

**Use Case / End Goal:**
My intentions is to make a portable application that tracks (detects) what computer/ computer setup you are using and displays the appropriate desktop. One example is on my work computer with a large monitor it lays out my desktop one way and then on my laptop it hides some things; long story short it would show an alternate desktop display (less icons, only the ones I need for work/ home).

I have all that extra stuff worked out but I need a way to track not just what computer I am on but which monitors I have attached at the time. Essentially a "MAC address" for attached monitors; I know that is not a thing. This way on a triple monitor setup for example my application knows what goes where. Then if I remove one monitor it knows what to change to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long story short there just is no way to accurately detect in Java which monitor is which in the GraphicsDevice API. There are several other ways to detect this information but again Java runs into the same problem. Java just auto increments the monitors it finds like so:

Display0, 
Display1, 
Display2
...And so on.

Each time the computer turns on different monitor assignments can happen and each time a monitor turns off the order can change. The same is true if the graphics driver crashes or reboots while in use.

**One Solution**
This does not solve my original issue: The OP's questions. However I know it is extremely hard to get full human readable system information with Java, especially all attached monitors. I put in a request to [dbwiddis](https://github.com/dbwiddis) on GitHub and he was able to add this feature to [Oshi](https://github.com/dblock/oshi). His Java library pulls everything you need to know about every attached monitor to a computer. A perfect all in one solution for Network Admins.

**The Issue Still / Hack**
There still is no way (including using other API's accessible through other programming languages) to detect which monitor is which. The "MAC Address" of all your attached monitors if you will. The only way to do this reliably (really a hack) is to pop up a terminal that outputs information that you then can grab with Java. This way Java can manually make the matches. It can go out to Display2 and read the terminal window that is open on it and now we know which monitor is Display2.

I have no code for this right now because it is extremely unreliable and not guaranteed to be cross OS compatible. It should work fine in windows but your will need to execute a batch file or powershell script to get the terminals on the monitors you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just look at the `GraphicsDevice` API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getIDstring%28%29

Comment: I have read and tested the GraphicsDevice API. The getIDString() only returns basic information such as Display0 and Display1. With 3+ monitors for example simply plugging them in in a different order would change which ID they were assigned.